# Converting thousands of XML files to a CSV or analysis in R

Tags: xml, r

I'm an R data scientist who is used to flat files in a CSV, but I was sent a large dataset (12GB) that is just hundreds of thousands of XML files. I'd like to know how I can stitch these xml files together into a csv or something I can analyze with R.

The config.txt has some terms I'm unfamiliar with, which I'll paste below, in the hopes that it helps some

```
# parameters

THRESHOLD       0.7
REMOVE_STOPWORDS    true
WRITE_MERGED_FILES  true
OUTPUT_STATS        true
SIMILARITY      jaccard
OPERATOR        or
N_GRAMS         3
PAGE_LIMIT      1
BUILD_INDEX             false


# matching features to use

MATCH_TITLE     true
MATCH_AUTHORS       false
MATCH_PAGE_COUNT    false
MATCH_VENUE     false

# paths

# SOLR url
BASE_URL        http://davos2.ist.psu.edu:8983/solr/collection1

# DBLP xml file
DBLP_PATH       input/dblp.xml

# file containing the paths for the CiteSeer xml files
CITESEER_PATH       input/citeseerx-pub.rev.txt
```

There is also a `hits.txt` file, which is a 160MG file with lines like this

```
doi                       hits            time                     

10.1.1.1.1484             12              2.207                    
10.1.1.1.1485             4               0.307
```

I'm sure this is some kind of standard format, I just can't seem to find out how to get it into R. Here's the reference paper

http://www.cse.unt.edu/~ccaragea/papers/ecir14.pdf

The XML files are hierarchically structured data on Citeseer articles

Thank you and happy to provide more information

Comment: Could you please post a simple example of the XML file you want to parse? That paper seems to indicate that they have a Java tool for working with the data. Have you checked that out yet?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the R project, I dot recognise that format. If you need to get XML files into csv format yourself, you most likely need to write some script or code for it, since XML files are typically hierarchical, and csv files have a flat structure. To represent the XML structure in csv, you can do:

```
<tag>A</tag>
    <next>B</next>
        <value>C</value>
    <value>D</value>
```

to file.csv
    A,B,C
    A,B,D

, as in, repeat the data. If you know any script or programming language, I can suggest more. If you'd need a tool, I'd search online. But hopefully, someone recognises the data format.